# Bootstrap-italia app crash (Opzione non valida - "bootstrap-italia")

Tags: bootstrap-5

Sto avendo dei problemi con il playground di bootstrap-italia.
Non riesco in nessun modo a far partire il progetto in locale.
Dopo aver clonato la repo sul mio pc ho seguito pedissequamente il breve e semplice file read.me che spiega di fare 3 passaggi:

```
- npm i
- npm run serve
- aprire il link http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

Ma ogni volta l'app crasha e mi renderizza solo l'html, vi allego cosa mi dice il terminale:

```
$ npm run serve

> bootstrap-italia-playground@2.0.0 serve
> concurrently --kill-others "npm-watch" "browser-sync start --server --no-inject-changes --files 'css/**/*.css'"

[0] No task specified. Will go through all possible tasks
[0] [nodemon] 2.0.22
[0] [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter rs
[0] [nodemon] watching path(s): index.html scss\**\*
[0] [nodemon] watching extensions: html,scss
[0] [nodemon] starting npm.cmd run -s build
[1] [Browsersync] Access URLs:
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]        Local: http://localhost:3000
[1]     External: http://192.168.1.101:3000
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1]           UI: http://localhost:3001
[1]  UI External: http://localhost:3001
[1]  --------------------------------------
[1] [Browsersync] Serving files from: ./
[1] [Browsersync] Watching files...
[0] Opzione non valida - "bootstrap-italia".
[0] [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Ho controllato che non ci fossero altri processi attivi di Node.js, ho aggiornato la versione, niente.
Mi trovo in alto mare al momento, spero nel vostro aiuto.

Grazie.

UPDATE: Provando ad avviare il progetto su un mac di un amico abbiamo notato che npm install non mi compila i file come dovrebbe, a parte node_modules tutto il resto non viene compilato.
Aggiungo anche che sono su windows.